# How Can I declare constraints in Xpress IVE?

Tags: modeling, mixed-integer-programming, integer-programming, mosel, xpress-optimizer

I am trying to write a model in Xpress IVE however I got
**error101: Incompatible types for operator ('mpvar' * 'mpvar' not defined).** error.

I tried to write this constraint but I couldn't make it.
**The two consecutive characters on the string must be positioned to the neighboring
nodes of the grid.**

I think, my model is true and all of my decision variables is true.

Can anyone help me about this issue?
Here is my code:

```
grid := 16
length := 8
!sample declarations section
declarations
    ! Declaring S and N array for the input
    S: array(1..length) of integer
    N: array(1..grid,1..grid) of integer
    ! Declaring decision variables
    X: array(1..length, 1..grid) of mpvar
    V: array(1..grid) of mpvar
    C: array(1..grid,1..grid) of mpvar
    W: real
    constraint1, constraint2,constraint3: linctr
end-declarations

! Decision Variable Declaration
forall(i in 1..length, k in 1..grid) X(i,k) is_binary
forall(k in 1..grid) V(k) is_binary
forall(l in 1..grid) V(l) is_binary
forall(k in 1..grid, l in 1..grid) C(k,l) is_binary

!Input String
S:: [ 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0 ]
! Neighbours in the grid. 
N:: [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]

! Finding consecutive 1's in the string
forall(i in 1..length-1) do
    if S(i) = 1 and S(i+1) = 1
    then W := W + 1
    end-if
end-do

! Declaring Constraints
! Constraint 1
forall(k in 1..grid) constraint1 := sum(i in 1..length) X(i,k) <= 1

! Constraint 2
forall(i in 1..length) constraint2 := sum(k in 1..grid) X(i,k) = 1

!Constraint 3
forall( i in 1..length - 1 ) constraint3 := (sum(j in 1..grid)(sum(k in 1..grid) N(k,j) * X(i,k) * X(i + 1,j))) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are creating the product of two variables in `Constraint3`, your problem is no longer linear but now quadratic (thus non-linear). This means you have to use the `mmnl` (non-linear) Mosel module. Putting

```
uses "mmnl"
```

at the top of your model should do that. It enables multiplication of decision variables.

Note that due to the quadratic terms in it, your `Constraint3` will no longer be of type `linctr`. It will now be `nlctr` and you have to adjust this in the declaration.